# Objective-C modify parameter to method at runtime

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'd like to change the value of a parameter at runtime and curious how this works in Obj-C.

I have a loop where value of 'n' is 0 increasing by 1 with each loop. How does one increment the passed parameter by 1 as n moves.

```
UIViewSubclass *uiViewSubclass = [[UIViewSubclass alloc] initWithValue:([value integerValue]) 
                                                   andPlacement:kPlacement0;
```

next time through loop I'd like 2nd argument to read as: **andPlacement:kPlacement1**;
and then: **andPlacement:kPlacement2**; and on...

do I make kPlacement a string and stringByAppendingString:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:n] stringValue]; ?

What's the Obj-C/Cocoa approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify your source code or make up variable references at runtime. Objective-C isn't *that* dynamic.

If the values of `kPlacement0` through `kPlacementMax` are sequential, you may be able to use a `for` loop to step through them directly:

```
for (MyPlacement placement = kPlacement0; placement += kPlacementIncrement; placement <= kPlacementMax) {
    UIViewSubclass *instanceOfUIViewSubclass = [[UIViewSubclass alloc] initWithValue:([value integerValue])
                                                                        andPlacement:placement];
    //Do something with instanceOfUIViewSubclass.
    [instanceOfUIViewSubclass release];
}
```

(You will need to define `kPlacementIncrement` and `kPlacementMax` in addition to the `kPlacement0`, etc. constants. I'm using `MyPlacement` as the name of your enumeration type that the `kPlacement0` etc. constants correspond to.)

If they are not sequential, put them in a C array and iterate on that array:

```
enum { numPlacements = <#Insert the number of placement constants here#> };
MyPlacement placements[numPlacements] = {
    kPlacement0,
    kPlacement1,
    kPlacement2,
    ⋮
}

for (unsigned i = 0U; i < numPlacements; ++i) {
    UIViewSubclass *instanceOfUIViewSubclass = [[UIViewSubclass alloc] initWithValue:([value integerValue])
                                                                        andPlacement:placements[i]];
    //Do something with instanceOfUIViewSubclass.
    [instanceOfUIViewSubclass release];
}
```

You probably can come up with more-descriptive names than `kPlacement0` etc. When you want to refer to them by number, do that; when you want to refer to them by name, give them good names.

Comment: To be more explicit: Anytime you find yourself tempted to have a bunch of variables named `suchandsuch1`, `suchandsuch2`, etc., you probably meant to use an array.